# Conditional function invocation using template

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Is there a way to conditionally invoke a function using c++ templates (compile time code generation), where based on the type of the arguments the logic will be different for each of the variation

for example (not compilable code),

```
template <true, typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
int func(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3) {//logic type1}

template <false, typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
int func(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3) {//logic type2}

template <typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
int foo(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3)
{
    func<static_condition>(v1, v2, v3);
}
```

when foo is invoked with some arguments it will statically evaluate boolean flag based on which it should invoke func. The logic being performed in these two variants will cause compilation error so it has to be split for each of the operation.

I was searching for some examples and found _If _Then _Else pattern using template meta programming but I am unclear on how to use that for my scenario.

Comment: If your question is about C++ make sure to add that tag (not clear if you are looking for C++ solution or some generic algorithm and using C++ as sample)

Comment: Included c++. I am looking for a c++ solution using templates as the method Iam working on is templated.

Comment: Have you looked into tag dispatching? When you say with "some" arguments, do you mean certain types?

Comment: Your two definitions of func are identical. How are you going to 'switch' between them?

Comment: @SergeyA fixed the copy paste.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing is easier.

```
template <typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
int func(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3, std::true_type) {//logic type1}

template <typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
int func(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3, std::false_type) {//logic type2}

template <typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
int foo(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3)
{
    func(v1, v2, v3, std::integral_constant<bool, static_condition>());
}
```

Comment: itym `std::integral_constant<bool, static_condition>{}`

Comment: @Yakk, most certainly!

Comment: And in C++17,  `std::bool_constant` for 10 fewer characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enable_if` to conditionally turn off one function or the other:

```
template <bool cond, typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
typename std::enable_if<cond, int>::type
func(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3) {//logic type1}

template <bool cond, typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
typename std::enable_if<not cond, int>::type
func(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3) {//logic type2}

template <typename Var1, typename Var2, typename Var3>
int foo(Var1 v1, Var2 v2, Var3 v3) {
    func<static_condition>(v1, v2, v3);
}
```